# MySql: Collation/charcter set which returns "München" for "Munchen" and at the same time "Göteborg" for "Gøteborg"

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

I have a website where Norwegian users should be able to search for city names.
The city of Munich is stored as "München".
The city of Gothenburg is stored as "Göteborg".

1. Users with a Norwegian keyboard will type "Munchen" when searching for "München".
   This is beacuse Norwegians do not use ü often and will type u which is the closest letter on the keyboard.
2. They will type "Gøteborg" when searching for "Göteborg". This is the same letter but looks different in Norwegian and Swedish.
   This also goes for cities with ä instead of æ.

**Collation tests**

**ut8_general_ci**
Munchen will give München. 
Gøteborg will not give Göteborg

**latin1_swedish_ci**
Munchen will not give München. 
Gøteborg will give Göteborg.

Is there a way/Collation that will support both these scenarios?

I use mysql 5.6.12

The preferred behavior can be found at [hotels.com](http://www.hotels.com) when searching for destinations.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check out [collation charts webdsite](http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/), where you can view for each collation which characters equal which. Those in a single line are equal each other. If you find a collation, where the described matches are present, then you have a hit. I would check out the various scandinavian ones or, [german ones.](http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.latin1_german1_ci.html).

Alternatively, you can create your own collation to [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-collation.html) with your desired weights. Obviously, you can base your collation on an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

[*My collation chart*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html) is more compact.

In many, but not all, utf8 collations, `Ø` is treated as a letter between `O` and `P`.  Ditto for `ö` in utf8_icelandic_ci and utf8_turkish_ci.  utf8_german2_ci treats it equal to `oe` and `œ`.  The others treat it equal to `o`.

The problem with collations is there there is no one collation that works for all languages.  utf8_unicode_ci and utf8_unicode_520_ci are perhaps the best compromises.  Even so, those two differ in the handling of `Ø`.

`ä=æ` only for utf8_german2_ci.  Slovak treats `ä` as a separate letter; the rest say `ä=a`.

You should not use latin1 if you want names outside of western Europe.

No collation will treat `Gothenburg`=`Göteborg`.  So, what you really need is a table of alternate spellings.  With that table, you could work around the problem with the Norwegians, etc.  (And, worse yet, Americans.)